# configure: error: Library dvdread > 4.9.0 needed for dvdread was not found

Tags: cmake, compilation, cross-compiling, vlc, qmake

I'm now compiling vlc source code. I referenced this document. https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/

I came across an error in configure step. The error is as follows;

```
configure: error: Library dvdread > 4.9.0 needed for dvdread was not found
```

I've installed all related libraries like libdvdread-dev, but the problem can't be solved.

I need a help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the docker image to avoid this kind of error https://code.videolan.org/videolan/docker-images/